# $.post is looking into the base url instead of the url given as parameter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

Calling filter_propert() from show_by_filter():

```
function show_by_filter(){
  var data = removed_code;
  $.post(" http://studentssaathi.com/application/controllers/Clients.php/filter_property",data, function(response) {
    $('.columns').html("");
    $('.columns').html(response);
   });
}
```

show_by_filter resides in assets/users/js/users.js

Getting ERROR: jquery.min.js:4 POST **http://studentssaathi.com/filter_property** 404 (Not Found)

I can't understand why it is looking for the function in the base url.

Code of controller (Clients.php):

```
public function filter_property(){
    $post_req = $this->input->post();
    $search_name = $post_req['search_name'];
    $filter_price = $post_req['price'];
    unset($post_req['search_name']);
    unset($post_req['price']);

    $result = $this->user_model->get_property_details($post_req, $search_name, $filter_price);
    $data = array();
    $data['result'] = $result;
    $this->load->view('users/login/home_content', $data);
}
```

Comment: it should be $.post('/controller/method/argument',d,f(r){})

Comment: @Vickel can you frame it for my use case?

Comment: what's your controller? clients.php? and the method you want to run? filter_property()? if so, you should write `$.post('/clients/filter_property',data,function(r){})`

Comment: Hi @RahulKumar not sure if it helps or not, I am thinking maybe data passed to $.post requires an object wrapping like { myData: data}, can you check this ?

Comment: @Vickel tried that, no luck.

Comment: maybe you want to edit your question and show not only the jquery code, but also the involved php controller (and eventually the model)

Comment: @Vickel have added the code from the controller Clients.php.

Comment: in order to receive theview page as html code you need to send it back to the ajax response as: `echo $this->load->view('users/login/home_content', $data, true);` the true parameter does this. that will only work, if all other code is producing correct result, pls. check

Comment: Please check your log then talk what is the correct error ! @rahul kumar

Comment: Getting ERROR: jquery.min.js:4 POST http://studentssaathi.com/filter_property 404 (Not Found).....    First of all, let me tell you that this is not the error of the JS, it was not getting the controller's page first, after that check js then  tell me.

Comment: I did $.post("clients/filter_property/",data, function(response) and it's working on Firefox but not on chrome!

Comment: you need a leading slash (before clients): $.post('/clients/filter_property',data,function(r){}), anyway what means "not working"?

Comment: I tried that also still no luck with chrome. Chrome is still showing POST http://studentssaathi.com/filter_property 404 (Not Found). But on firefox the filter is working now.

Comment: you should really check your browser console and network tab and check for any error indicated

Comment: you also might need to clear cache in chrome or refresh with Ctrl+F5

Comment: did that already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did `$.post("clients/filter_property/",data, function(response) {
    $('.columns').html("");
    $('.columns').html(response);
  });`

and it's working now!